# XYZ parameters not the default when placing an object

Tags: mesh

When I place an object or a mesh from the Add option, it is not set to the default parameters of 0 on XYZ as shown in the images, why is that, can this be fixed?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just after the add operation, before you do anything else, click on the black label on the bottom left of the 3D window and change the alignement option, from "view" to "World".

[image]

Comment: It sounds as if the New Objects 'Align To' setting may have been changed in Preferences > Editing. Set them to World and all should be right with the world! :^)